# SSRS 2014 Exec Log gives the Service Account as UserName instead of Actual User name

Tags: users, reporting, ssrs-2014

I am using the below query for accessing the Users who are using the Application Reports.

SSRS 2014 gives the Service Account(IIS Account used for Application) as User Name instead of Actual User name.

```
USE ReportServer;
GO
SELECT el2.username, 
el2.InstanceName, 
el2.ReportPath, 
el2.TimeStart, 
el2.TimeEnd, 
el2.[Status],
isnull(el2.Parameters, 'N/A') as Parameters 
FROM ExecutionLog2 el2
GO
```

Can you please let me know why I am not able to see exact username who accessed the Report instead why I am seeing the Service Account in the place of User Name exactly.

There is only one DISTINCT RequestType which is Interactive. Where as when we read IIS logs using Log parser it does contain the User Name individually

Thanks

Comment: How are your reports requested? You mention the IIS application pool identity but does that mean your web application requests the reports from the SSRS service? SSRS doesn't use IIS any more in 2014, it uses http.sys. Does  your IIS allow anonymous access?

Answer (score 0):

You may be seeing a [Subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/subscriptions-and-delivery-reporting-services) execution. You can spot-check this by...

- In the UI by going to the report listed on the `ReportPath` and going to <kbd>Manage > Subscriptions</kbd>
- In the DB by checking the `dbo.Subscriptions` table (see some helpful queries at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18960965/4709762))

Comment: Thanks @peter , just checked dbo.subscriptions does not show any values .